Configuring OIDC for my users to log into Ubuntu with
I'd like to be able to set up an Ubuntu installation so users can log into it via a company-managed Okta, ADFS, or similar OpenID connect login. Is this possible, either with vanilla Ubuntu, or with third party software added in?
